# CSS refused to display Image in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having trouble to display image in MVC application.

```
<div class="testimg" style="@Url.Content(" ~/Assets/images/pallavi.jpg") no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
```

Comment: Should there be a leading space in the Content string?

Comment: no i'm not define space in the Content string

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css url() to background images and you forgot the css property background-image:

```
<div class="testimg" style="background-image: url(@Url.Content(" ~/Assets/images/pallavi.jpg")) no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
```

Comment: well, you should debug if @Url.Content gives back a valid URL